# Help with properly discontinuous action implication in Milnor-Schwarz lemma.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, metric-spaces, group-actions, geometric-group-theory

From *Office Hours with a GGT*

> [image]
>   [image]

---

---

I am not seeing how proper discontinuity implies there are finitely many translates of $B$ that have distance at most $D$ from $B$.

Proper discontinuity says that if $K$ is compact, then $|\{g \in G \mid gK \cap K\}| < \infty$.

I take it that this can be rephrased as saying there are finitely many translates of $K$ that have distance zero from $K$?

So, there should be finitely many translates of $B$ that have distance $0$ from $B$.

How is the author concluding finitely many translates with distance at most $D$?

Comment: Apply proper continuity to $K = \{ x\in X \ |\ d(x_0, x) \leq D + r\}$.

Comment: @Neal Are we then looking at $B(x_0, D+R)$? Using the radius $D+R$, there are finitely many translates of $B$ that have distance less than or equal to $D+R$?

Comment: @Neal Ahh I think I see now. Considering $B(x_0, R+D)$, we can say there are finitely many translates of $B$ that have distance $0<t\le D$ from $B$ where the translations are coming from $g \in G \setminus S$.